# Can't Refresh radio buttons Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

After sending a form, I want to "clean it up" but unselecting the previous selected option.

This is the radio set:

```html
<div class="btn-group" id="btnRadio" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <span style="color: green;">
        <i class="fas fa-smile-beam"></i>
    </span>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="idRadioBien"> Bien
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <i class="far fa-meh"></i>
    </span>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="idRadioNormal"> Normal
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <span style="color: Tomato;">
        <i class="fas fa-sad-tear"></i>
    </span>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="idRadioMal"> Mal
    </label>
</div>
```

I can't get to "unselect" the chosen radio by the user.

After checking other Stack Overflow questions, I've tried "refreshing" the set with something like:

```js
 $('input:radio')
     .removeAttr('checked')
     .removeAttr('selected')
     .button("refresh");
```

but still no luck. It stays selected like this:

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on any radio button then `active` class is added to its *label* .So , to remove checked from radios you also need to remove that `active` class from label tag.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="buttons"] :radio').prop('checked', false); //remove checked if any
  $('[data-toggle="buttons"] label').removeClass('active'); //remove active class from label
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha512-OdEXQYCOldjqUEsuMKsZRj93Ht23QRlhIb8E/X0sbwZhme8eUw6g8q7AdxGJKakcBbv7+/PX0Gc2btf7Ru8cZA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="btn-group" id="btnRadio" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm active">
        <span style="color: green;">
        <i class="fas fa-smile-beam"></i>
    </span>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="idRadioBien" checked> Bien
    </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
     <span style="">
        <i class="far fa-meh"></i>
    </span>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="idRadioNormal"> Normal
    </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <span style="color: Tomato;">
        <i class="fas fa-sad-tear"></i>
    </span>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="idRadioMal"> Mal
    </label>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

prop checked to false ?

```js
$('input:radio').prop('checked', false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" id="btnRadio" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <span style="color: green;">
        <i class="fas fa-smile-beam"></i>
    </span>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="idRadioBien" checked> Bien
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <i class="far fa-meh"></i>
    </span>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="idRadioNormal"> Normal
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <span style="color: Tomato;">
        <i class="fas fa-sad-tear"></i>
    </span>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="idRadioMal"> Mal
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry I didnt follow you. No, the prop was set to false and it's still selected. I can't unselect it to present it again without the option preselected.